# как извлечь долготу и широту из gpx файла python в ручную без библиотек

Tags: python

```
    <trk>
    <trkseg>
        <trkpt lat="54.872375" lon="83.1026">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.87237" lon="83.1026">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.872375" lon="83.1026">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.872383" lon="83.1026">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.87239" lon="83.10262">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.8724" lon="83.102646">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.872406" lon="83.10268">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.872417" lon="83.102715">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.872433" lon="83.10276">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.87245" lon="83.1028">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.4705882)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.6896551</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.872467" lon="83.10284">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.1764705)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.85470086</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.87248" lon="83.10287">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=0.990099)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>1.0204082</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.872494" lon="83.1029">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.872513" lon="83.102936">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=1.8)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>0.5555556</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.87253" lon="83.10297">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=0.71428573)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>1.4084507</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="54.87255" lon="83.103">
            <ele>128.0</ele>
            <time>2022-10-09T00:51:52Z</time>
            <desc><![CDATA[CommonTimeValuePoint(absoluteTime=1665276712, value=0.6711409)]]></desc>
                <extensions>
                    <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                        <ns3:speed>1.5151515</ns3:speed>
                        <ns3:cad>0.0</ns3:cad>
                        <ns3:hr>111</ns3:hr>
                    </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
                </extensions>
        </trkpt>
```

Comment: Для такого файла подойдёт Regex - вылавливаем из <trkpt lat="54.87255" lon="83.103"> lat и lon. /<trkpt\s+lat="(.*)"\s+lon="(.*)">/gm

Comment: мне нужно без библиотек

Comment: А как вы думаете это можно осуществить?

Comment: я сейчас сижу с другом и у него получилось

Comment: Отличный друг! может разместит тогда ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я напишу линейно, чтобы понятно было смысл:
text = [Ваша строка из gpx]

```
try:
    idxStart = text.index('<trkpt lat="')
    idxEnd = text.index('>', idxStart)
except ValueError :
    print('Error')
    exit()

textFound = text[idxStart:idxEnd]
print(textFound)

try:
    idxStartQuot = textFound.index('"')
    idxStartQuot += 1
    idxEndQuot = textFound.index('"', idxStartQuot)
except ValueError :
    print('Error')
    exit()

lat = textFound[idxStartQuot:idxEndQuot]

try:
    idxStartQuot = textFound.index('"',idxEndQuot+2)
    idxStartQuot += 1
    idxEndQuot = textFound.index('"', idxStartQuot)
except ValueError :
    print('Error')
    exit()

lon = textFound[idxStartQuot:idxEndQuot]

print(f'lat = {lat} lon = {lon}')
```

Вывод:

<trkpt lat="54.872375" lon="83.1026"

lat = 54.872375 lon = 83.1026

Ну дальше оптимизируйте и т.п.